# Is there a way to convert compiled html from Angular 5 to plain html & css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

I'm using angular 5 to build the web pages on the frontend side. 
One of these pages is a fixed HTML page and SASS Style, it's a combination of different components.

I need a way to generate HTML & CSS of this page in one file, without any HTML component elements just plain HTML & CSS.

**Example**

I have nested components as the following:

```
<router-outlet name="header"></router-outlet>
<leftside-bar _nghost-c11=""></leftside-bar>
```

I need the output file without these elements, I need it to be plain HTML.

Is there a way to generate a file or plain HTML Code from the Angular component?

Comment: What's your use case? So you just want the resulting html but not have the component's interactions? So if you've got a button ot will not do anything when you click? Resulting html will contain component tags in any case

Comment: it's not click event, I just need any library or any script can I do to generate plain HTML as the output page without any angular component elements.